# Extracting specific fields from Data in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

This is the Ruby program in which I have to extract specific fields using Regular expression from the data in a file.
The data in the file is in the following format:

Nov 13 01:46:57 10.232.47.76 qas-adaptiveip-10-232-47-76 2015-11-13 01:46:57 +0000 [info]: qas-296d1fa95fd0ac5a84ea73234c0c48d64f6ea22d has been deregistered adap_tdagt

I need to extract the following values 
1)2015-11-13 01:46:57 +0000
2)qas-296d1fa95fd0ac5a84ea73234c0c48d64f6ea22d

I have written the code but it's not working properly. Can someone please help me out with this problem.

```
  class Task5
  def initialize
  #   @f=File.open('C:/Users/aroraku/Desktop,boc-adap_td-agent.log-2.log',r)
  @count=0
  end

  def check_line(line)
      if(line=~/deregistered adap_tdagt$/)
           line=~ (/.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} +\d{4})/)
               puts "#{$1}"
      end
  end

  def file_read
     open("boc-adap_td-agent.log-2.log") { |f|
          while line=f.gets do
             check_line(line)
          end
     }
    # return @count
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to explain what you know about the string. Will it always contain `" [info]: "` between the two fields of interest? Will the non-date you want to capture always be at the end of the string? If the string contains multiple substrings that meet the conditions, do you want to extract them all? Please clarify by editing the question.

Comment: Yes, The fields will always be like the one as shown in example...Thanks

Comment: I wish to offer a couple of suggestions for how you might have improved your question. (Don't change it now, however.) Firstly, I'm sure you know how to read a text file into a string, so best to frame the question around the string and make no reference to where it came from. Secondly, your example's data should always be valid Ruby objects, with the value of each object held by a variable you define; for example, `str = "Nov 13...adap_tdagt"`. That way, readers can refer to those variables (here `str`) in comments and answers without having to define them.

Answer (score 4):

```
str = "Nov 13 01:46:57 10.232.47.76 qas-adaptiveip-10-232-47-76 2015-11-13 01:46:57 +0000 [info]: qas-296d1fa95fd0ac5a84ea73234c0c48d64f6ea22d has been deregistered adap_tdagt"
```

As the problem with your code has been identified, I would like to suggest another way to extract the desired information from each line:

```
r = /
    (?:                # begin a non-capture group
      \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\+\d{4} # match date string
    )                  # end non-capture group
    |                  # or
    (?:                # begin a non-capture group
      (?<=\[info\]:\s) # match "[info:] " in a positive lookbehind
      \S+              # match >= 1 characters other than whitespace
    )                  # end non-capture group
    /x                 # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

str.scan(r)
  #=> ["2015-11-13 01:46:57 +0000", "qas-296d1fa95fd0ac5a84ea73234c0c48d64f6ea22d"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You must escape `+` sign for date:

```
line =~ /.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \+\d{4}).+([a-z]{3}-[a-f0-9]{40})/
puts $1 # 2015-11-13 01:46:57 +0000
puts $2 # qas-296d1fa95fd0ac5a84ea73234c0c48d64f6ea22d
```